# Eclipse C++ - how to go to definition OF TYPE of highlighted variable DIRECTLY

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

When you highlight a variable and press `F3 (Go To Declaration)`, it takes you to the declaration of the variable . . . and then you can highlight the type and press `F3 (Go To Declaration)` again to see the type definition.

I want to be able to highlight a variable and go directly to its **type** definition.

Is there a shortcut like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not.

Consider [filing an issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT) to have one added.